# How to make window scrollable instead of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have an issue where the scrollbar is attached to `content-box` and not to `window`. `content-box` is not the full width of `window`, which makes an awkward scroll bar in the middle. How would I move the scrollbar to `window`?

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dbgpvnyj/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="header">Title</div>
         <div id="content-box" tabindex="0">
            <div class="content">content</div>
            <div class="content">content</div>
            ...
            <div class="content">content</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

#content-box {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `content-box { height: auto; }`. An element is only scrollable if the element's height is smaller then the content. Simply set the elements height to `auto` so the height will be calculated to `fit-content`

Comment: The mere HTML code you have shown, does not actually reproduce the issue. Please provide a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question.

Comment: @CBroe - apologies for the oversight. Added the data

Comment: @tacoshy - this doesn't work (see fiddle)

Answer (score -2):

```
body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This will make the scrollbar appear on the window instead of the content-box.

Comment: [This doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/dbgpvnyj/3/)

Comment: remove #content-box and .container css it works, otherwise change their values

Comment: There's other CSS in there. I cannot just remove entire CSS sections. What would I change the values to?

Comment: its not the body that overflows but the html document as whole. However this is a default setting and as such won't do anything.